# Why can't I call my enemy boundaries in my player function?

Tags: python, pygame

Why can't I call my enemy boundaries in my player function? I'm relatively new to python and I am literally drawing a blank.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 255, 255)
DISPLAY_WIDTH = 800
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 600
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
bg = pygame.image.load('background.png')

def textObjects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()
def messageDisplay(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
    textSurf, textRect = textObjects(text, largeText)
    textRect.center = ((DISPLAY_WIDTH/2), (DISPLAY_HEIGHT/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    char = pygame.image.load('Rbear.png')
    walkRight = [pygame.image.load('Rwalk1.png'), pygame.image.load('Rwalk2.png'), pygame.image.load('Rwalk3.png'), pygame.image.load('Rwalk4.png'), pygame.image.load('Rwalk5.png'), pygame.image.load('Rwalk6.png')] 
    walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('Lwalk1.png'), pygame.image.load('Lwalk2.png'), pygame.image.load('Lwalk3.png'), pygame.image.load('Lwalk4.png'), pygame.image.load('Lwalk5.png'), pygame.image.load('Lwalk6.png')] 
    frames = 0
    def __init__(self):


        super().__init__()

        self.rightIs = False
        self.leftIs = False
        self.right_pressed = False
        self.left_pressed = False
        self.canLeft = True
        self.canRight = True
        width = 90
        height = 150
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.waitBit = 5

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


        self.xVel = 0
        self.yVel = 0



        self.level = None

    def update(self):
        self.calc_grav()
        self.waitBit += 1
        self.frames += 1
        if self.frames+1 >= 18:
            self.frames = 0
        if self.rightIs == True:
            self.image = self.walkRight[self.frames//3]
        elif self.leftIs == True:
            self.image = self.walkLeft[self.frames//3]
        else:
            self.image = self.char

        self.level.bgX += self.xVel


        self.correction = 0


        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.right_pressed == True:
                self.correction = self.rect.right - block.rect.left
            if self.left_pressed == True:
                self.correction = self.rect.left - block.rect.right

        if self.correction != 0:
            for block in self.level.platform_list:
                block.rect.x += self.correction
            self.level.level_limit -= self.correction
            block.boundary_left += self.correction
            block.boundary_right += self.correction



        self.rect.y += self.yVel


        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.yVel > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            if self.yVel < 0:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom


            self.yVel = 0

            if isinstance(block, MovingPlatform):
                if self.rightIs == True:
                    self.xVel = -block.xVel - 10
                elif self.leftIs == True:
                    self.xVel = -block.xVel + 10
                else:
                    self.xVel = -block.xVel

    def calc_grav(self):
        if self.yVel == 0:
            self.yVel = 1
        else:
            self.yVel +=0.3

        if self.rect.y >= DISPLAY_HEIGHT - self.rect.height and self.yVel >= 0:
            self.yVel = 0
            self.rect.y = DISPLAY_HEIGHT - self.rect.height


    def jump(self):
        self.rect.y += 2
        platform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        self.rect.y -= 2


        if len(platform_hit_list) > 0 or self.rect.bottom >= DISPLAY_HEIGHT:
            self.yVel = -10

    def moveLeft(self):

        self.xVel = 10

    def moveRight(self):

        self.xVel = -10

    def friction(self):

        self.xVel = 0


class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(GREEN)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


class MovingPlatform(Platform):

    xVel = 0
    yVel = 0

    boundary_top = 0
    boundary_bottom = 0
    boundary_left = 0
    boundary_right = 0

    player = None

    level = None

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.xVel
        self.player.correction = 0
        hit = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, self.player)
        if hit:

            if self.xVel < 0:
                self.player.correction = self.player.rect.right - self.rect.left
            else:
                self.player.correction = self.player.rect.left - self.rect.right


        if self.player.correction != 0:
            for self in self.level.platform_list:
                self.rect.x += self.player.correction
            self.level.level_limit -= self.player.correction
            self.boundary_left += self.player.correction
            self.boundary_right += self.player.correction

        self.rect.y += self.yVel


        hit = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, self.player)
        if hit:

            if self.yVel < 0:
                self.player.rect.bottom = self.rect.top
            else:
                self.player.rect.top = self.rect.bottom

        if self.rect.bottom > self.boundary_bottom or self.rect.top < self.boundary_top:
            self.yVel *= -1

        cur_pos = self.rect.x - self.level.bgX
        if cur_pos < self.boundary_left or cur_pos > self.boundary_right:
            self.xVel *= -1
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(GREEN)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Cat(Enemy):

    xVel = 0
    yVel = 0

    boundary_top = 0
    boundary_bottom = 0
    boundary_left = 0
    boundary_right = 0

    player = None

    level = None

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.xVel
        hit = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, self.player)
        if hit:
            self.player.yVel = -10

        if self.rect.bottom > self.boundary_bottom or self.rect.top < self.boundary_top:
            self.yVel *= -1

        cur_pos = self.rect.x - self.level.bgX
        if cur_pos < self.boundary_left or cur_pos > self.boundary_right:
            self.xVel *= -1

        if self.player.correction != 0:
            catEnemy.rect.x += self.correction
            catEnemy.boundary_left += self.correction
            catEnemy.boundary_right += self.correction


class Level(object):

    def __init__(self, player):
        self.platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = player

        self.background = None


        self.bgX = 0
        self.level_limit = -1000

    def update(self):
        self.platform_list.update()
        self.enemy_list.update()

    def draw(self, screen):

        gameDisplay.blit(bg,(0,0))


        self.platform_list.draw(screen)
        self.enemy_list.draw(screen)

        for platform in self.platform_list:
            platform.rect.x += self.player.xVel

        for enemy in self.enemy_list:
            enemy.rect.x += self.player.xVel

class Level_01(Level):

    def __init__(self, player):


        Level.__init__(self, player)

        self.level_limit = -1500


        level = [[210, 70, 500, 500],
                 [210, 70, 800, 400],
                 [210, 70, 1000, 500],
                 [210, 70, 1120, 280],
                 ]


        for platform in level:
            block = Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
            block.rect.x = platform[2]
            block.rect.y = platform[3]
            block.player = self.player
            self.platform_list.add(block)


        block = MovingPlatform(100, 40)
        block.rect.x = 1350
        block.rect.y = 280
        block.boundary_left = 1350
        block.boundary_right = 1600
        block.xVel = -1
        block.player = self.player
        block.level = self
        self.platform_list.add(block)

        catEnemy = Cat(100, 100)
        catEnemy.rect.x = 1350
        catEnemy.rect.y = 500
        catEnemy.boundary_left = 1350
        catEnemy.boundary_right = 1600
        catEnemy.xVel = -1
        catEnemy.player = self.player
        catEnemy.level = self
        self.enemy_list.add(catEnemy)



class Level_02(Level):

    def __init__(self, player):

        Level.__init__(self, player)

        self.level_limit = -1500 - self.bgX


        level = [[210, 70, 500, 550],
                 [210, 70, 800, 400],
                 [210, 70, 1000, 500],
                 [210, 70, 1120, 280],
                 ]


        for platform in level:
            block = Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
            block.rect.x = platform[2]
            block.rect.y = platform[3]
            block.player = self.player
            self.platform_list.add(block)

        block = MovingPlatform(70, 70)
        block.rect.x = 1500
        block.rect.y = 300
        block.boundary_top = 100
        block.boundary_bottom = 550
        block.yVel = -1
        block.player = self.player
        block.level = self
        self.platform_list.add(block)

        catEnemy = Cat(100, 100)
        catEnemy.rect.x = 1350
        catEnemy.rect.y = 500
        catEnemy.boundary_left = 1350
        catEnemy.boundary_right = 1600
        catEnemy.xVel = -1
        catEnemy.player = self.player
        catEnemy.level = self
        self.enemy_list.add(catEnemy)

def main():
    pygame.init()


    size = [DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    pygame.display.set_caption("Platformer with moving platforms")
    player = Player()

    level_list = []
    level_list.append(Level_01(player))
    level_list.append(Level_02(player))

    current_level_no = 0
    current_level = level_list[current_level_no]

    active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player.level = current_level

    player.rect.x = 350
    player.rect.y = DISPLAY_HEIGHT - player.rect.height
    active_sprite_list.add(player)


    done = False


    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # -------- Main Program Loop -----------
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.jump()

                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and player.canRight==True:
                    player.right_pressed=True
                    player.rightIs = True
                    player.moveRight()
                    player.canLeft=False
                    player.left_pressed=False

                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and player.canLeft==True:
                    player.left_pressed=True
                    player.leftIs = True
                    player.moveLeft()
                    player.canRight=False
                    player.right_pressed=False

                if player.rightIs == True and player.leftIs == True:
                    player.friction()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.rightIs = False
                    player.canLeft = True
                    player.friction()
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.leftIs = False
                    player.canRight = True
                    player.friction()



        active_sprite_list.update()

        current_level.update()


        current_position = current_level.bgX
        if current_position < current_level.level_limit:
            if current_level_no < len(level_list)-1:
                player.rect.x = 350
                current_level_no += 1
                current_level = level_list[current_level_no]
                player.level = current_level
            else:
                done = True


        current_level.draw(screen)
        active_sprite_list.draw(screen)



        clock.tick(60)


        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is my enemy function:

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

        def __init__(self, width, height):
            super().__init__()

            self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
            self.image.fill(GREEN)

            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    class Cat(Enemy):

        xVel = 0
        yVel = 0

        boundary_top = 0
        boundary_bottom = 0
        boundary_left = 0
        boundary_right = 0

        player = None

        level = None

        def update(self):
            self.rect.x += self.xVel
            hit = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, self.player)
            if hit:
                self.player.yVel = -10

            if self.rect.bottom > self.boundary_bottom or self.rect.top < self.boundary_top:
                self.yVel *= -1

            cur_pos = self.rect.x - self.level.bgX
            if cur_pos < self.boundary_left or cur_pos > self.boundary_right:
                self.xVel *= -1

            if self.player.correction != 0:
                catEnemy.rect.x += self.correction
                catEnemy.boundary_left += self.correction
                catEnemy.boundary_right += self.correction
```

Here is my player class:

```
 class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    char = pygame.image.load('Rbear.png')
    walkRight = [pygame.image.load('Rwalk1.png'), pygame.image.load('Rwalk2.png'), pygame.image.load('Rwalk3.png'), pygame.image.load('Rwalk4.png'), pygame.image.load('Rwalk5.png'), pygame.image.load('Rwalk6.png')] 
    walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('Lwalk1.png'), pygame.image.load('Lwalk2.png'), pygame.image.load('Lwalk3.png'), pygame.image.load('Lwalk4.png'), pygame.image.load('Lwalk5.png'), pygame.image.load('Lwalk6.png')] 
    frames = 0
    def __init__(self):


        super().__init__()

        self.rightIs = False
        self.leftIs = False
        self.right_pressed = False
        self.left_pressed = False
        self.canLeft = True
        self.canRight = True
        width = 90
        height = 150
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.waitBit = 5

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


        self.xVel = 0
        self.yVel = 0



        self.level = None

    def update(self):
        self.calc_grav()
        self.waitBit += 1
        self.frames += 1
        if self.frames+1 >= 18:
            self.frames = 0
        if self.rightIs == True:
            self.image = self.walkRight[self.frames//3]
        elif self.leftIs == True:
            self.image = self.walkLeft[self.frames//3]
        else:
            self.image = self.char

        self.level.bgX += self.xVel


        self.correction = 0


        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.right_pressed == True:
                self.correction = self.rect.right - block.rect.left
            if self.left_pressed == True:
                self.correction = self.rect.left - block.rect.right

        if self.correction != 0:
            for block in self.level.platform_list:
                block.rect.x += self.correction
            self.level.level_limit -= self.correction
            block.boundary_left += self.correction
            block.boundary_right += self.correction



        self.rect.y += self.yVel


        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.yVel > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            if self.yVel < 0:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom


            self.yVel = 0

            if isinstance(block, MovingPlatform):
                if self.rightIs == True:
                    self.xVel = -block.xVel - 10
                elif self.leftIs == True:
                    self.xVel = -block.xVel + 10
                else:
                    self.xVel = -block.xVel

    def calc_grav(self):
        if self.yVel == 0:
            self.yVel = 1
        else:
            self.yVel +=0.3

        if self.rect.y >= DISPLAY_HEIGHT - self.rect.height and self.yVel >= 0:
            self.yVel = 0
            self.rect.y = DISPLAY_HEIGHT - self.rect.height


    def jump(self):
        self.rect.y += 2
        platform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        self.rect.y -= 2


        if len(platform_hit_list) > 0 or self.rect.bottom >= DISPLAY_HEIGHT:
            self.yVel = -10

    def moveLeft(self):

        self.xVel = 10

    def moveRight(self):

        self.xVel = -10

    def friction(self):

        self.xVel = 0
```

Here is where I want to call my Enemy function: (Located within the Player class):

```
if self.correction != 0:
    for block in self.level.platform_list:
    block.rect.x += self.correction
self.level.level_limit -= self.correction
block.boundary_left += self.correction
block.boundary_right += self.correction
```

This is what I was doing previously:

```
if self.correction != 0:
        for block in self.level.platform_list:
        block.rect.x += self.correction
    self.level.level_limit -= self.correction
    block.boundary_left += self.correction
    block.boundary_right += self.correction
    catEnemy.boundary_left += self.correction
    catEnemy.boundary_right += self.correction
```

Comment: *"Why can't I call my enemy boundaries in my player function?"* - What is the issue? Do you get an error?

Comment: please read about [ask] and specifically about giving a [mre]. Also try to be more clear of what you are trying to do, what is going wrong and how you expect it to go

Comment: What do you mean by "call" your enemy boundaries? "`call`" is what you do to things like functions, classes, and other callables. Also Is your indentation correct? It looks like you're defining nested classes...

Comment: Alright. I'm trying to update my catEnemy boundaries, but when I put the code at the bottom of my question is it says that catEnemy is not defined. How do I define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to update my `catEnemy` boundaries, but when I put the code at the bottom of my question is it says that `catEnemy` is not defined. [...]

This is, because `catEnemy` is a local variable in scope of `Level_01.__init__` (the constructor of `Level_01`).
If you want to make `catEnemy` a variable in global namespace, then you've to use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt):

```
class Level_01(Level):

    def __init__(self, player):
        # [...]

        global catEnemy

        catEnemy = Cat(100, 100) 

        # [...]
```